# Probability exercise regarding distributing $100$ balls of $4$ colors to $5$ children

Tags: probability

I have a homework problem that I am struggling to solve. I need a couple of hints that will help me, but I don't want the full solution.

Given 100 balls with different colours (25 each of red, blue, yellow, and green), we randomly divide the balls among 5 children (i.e. they receive 20 each).

1. What is the probability that the first two children received 10 red balls?
2. Given that the first two children received 10 red balls, what is the probability that the rest of the reds were divided equally among the other children?

Comment: **Hint.** Consider the first $2$ children as one block and the other 3 children another block. For every ball, you have probability $2/5$ of choosing the first block and $3/5$ of choosing the second. Can you continue from there?

Comment: For two, if $A$ and $B$ each are given $10$ red balls, then there are $5$ reds left, to divide amongst three children, which is not possible to divide evenly. Unless by "received 10 red balls" you mean "received at least 10 balls."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few hints:

1. It might make things easier if you just split red/non-red. The other colors don't really matter.
2. For exactly 10 red balls there is a formula where you choose 10 out of 25, another 10 out of 75. Out of a total solution space of 20 out of 100.
3. You can leave the formula in the answer. You don't need the exact value
4. For the second child, the numbers in the formula are slightly different.
5. How many red balls are left, how many children? Would division lead to an integer solution?